# React-Native -IOS Build - Noop-file.m not found

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Today is day 4 of trying upgrade my projects libraries for my react-native project. No idea if I am getting closer, but todays error is not found in any google searches I have made. Upon building I get this error:

```
.../noop-file.m Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/userxyz/product_abc/node_modules/expo-updates-interface/ios/EXUpdatesInterface/noop-file.m'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
```

Has anyone seen this before and know what could be the problem?

This appeared after I updated my delegate files. here they are:

### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UMCore/UMAppDelegateWrapper.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"YourAppName" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // You can inject any extra modules that you would like here, more information at:
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#dependency-injection
  return extraModules;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
#ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

#if RCT_DEV
- (BOOL)bridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge didNotFindModule:(NSString *)moduleName {
  return YES;
}
#endif


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

@end
```

Comment: Found any fix for this?

Comment: No, gave up on the application.